# Powershell command to wait some time

Tags: windows, powershell, sleep

How can I stop a powershell script execution for an x time and that continue after it?
So, for example, I can run a command and wait 3 seconds to display the user a log, then continue with other script execution.

Comment: [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Why not post this as an answer, @SantiagoSquarzon? I suggest also mentioning that `Get-Help sleep` would have allowed discovery of the command.

Comment: @mklement0  I thought that with a comment linking to MS Docs was enough :)

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, yes, @SantiagoSquarzon, but it's always preferable to have a proper answer, which also allows for providing additional information and proper formatting. Also, only _answers_ can be accepted - as the strongest signal that a solution works - and people generally tend to trust comments less.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Stack Exchange recommends that comments _not_ be used for answering questions; it "breaks" the defined model. (That said, I've been known to do the same thing...)

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the feedback. I felt that this question was answered here before and probably more than one time, in addition, simply by copy pasting the title of this question in google would've given OP the answer to his question hence why I felt like a comment was more than enough in this case. Next time I'll abstain to provide answers in comments, sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you too for the feedack, @SantiagoSquarzon, and no need to be sorry; providing the crucial hint in comment isn't a problem per se, it's just that it's _better_ to have a proper answer, and it seemed quite easy to transform your comment into an answer, which is why I encouraged you to do so. Separately, if a question is a _duplicate_, it is ultimately more helpful to spend time locating one and voting to close the question with a link to it. I do understand that sometimes all one has time for / wants to spend time on is a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft provides the [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet specifically for this purpose. By default, its parameter is the number of seconds to sleep; if you need finer control over the idle period, you can specify `-Milliseconds` as the unit of time to use.